# Сброс стиля при клике на другой блок на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

Задумка была следующей: Есть блок с обработчиком:

```
<div onclick="input_fn(this)";>
```

При клике срабатывает функция, закрашивающая блок в цвет:

```
function input_fn(elem){
    if (elem.style.backgroundColor == "") {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "#eb1a1a";
    } 
    else {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
}
```

При клике на 2 блок цвет 1 должен сброситься до стандартного, а у 2 соответственно измениться и т.д.

полный код:

```
function input_fn(elem){
    if (elem.style.backgroundColor == "") {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "#eb1a1a";
    } 
    else {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
}

<div onclick="input_fn(this)";>test</div>
<div onclick="input_fn(this)";>test2</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать идею под IE11. Заранее благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае, можно так:

```js
var moo = document.querySelectorAll('.moo');
var active = moo[0]; // moo[0], чтобы при первом клике не было ошибки.

for( var i = 0; i < moo.length; i++ ){
  moo[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    if( active == this ){
      // Если active ссылается на тот же объект, что и this (на кликнутую кнопку)
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    } else {
      active.classList.remove('active');
      this.classList.add('active');
      
      active = this;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.moo.active {
  background-color: #c00;
}
```

```html
<div class="moo">test-1</div>
<div class="moo">test-2</div>
<div class="moo">test-3</div>
<div class="moo">test-4</div>
<div class="moo">test-5</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function input_fn(elem) {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.active')].forEach(activeElement => {
    // находим все элементы с классом active и перебираем их
    activeElement.style.backgroundColor = ''; // удаляем цвет background
    activeElement.classList.remove('active'); // удаляем active класс
  });

  elem.classList.add('active'); // добавляем класс к текущему элементу что бы его можно было потом найти в DOM
  elem.style.backgroundColor = '#eb1a1a'; // добавляем цвет фона
}
```